# C# SharpZipLib write a file directly into zip

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

my process needs to create a zip file with a large number of files(that are also created by the process). Instead of having to create temporary files, zipping them and then deleting, can I directly add files into a zip file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. But the performance of it will be poor compared to direct file creation. Anyway, [SharpDevelop Wiki](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib_Updating.ashx) has examples.